# Getting an error with react-native-tcp-socket, is there an alternative?

Tags: react-native, tcp

I basically need to send a file via TCP, and the only thing I found for React Native was `react-native-tcp-socket`, however when I try to create a connection it throws me this error:

> `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNativeTcpSocket.TcpSocket.createConnection')`

I don't know what's the problem, I'm using Expo, I already ejected the code if that was needed.

Here's the code:

```js
const options = {
                        port: Port,
                        host: IP,
                    };
const client =         TcpSocket.createConnection(options, () => {
                        client.write(Payload);
                        client.destroy();

                    });
                    client.on("error", function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    });
                    client.on("close", function () {
                        console.log("Connection closed!");
                    });
```

So how could I fix this issue? Or is there any other way to use TCP sockets in react native?

Comment: Your code contains TAB characters. Maybe re-add the code expanding TABs to spaces for proper alignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if anyone comes here, first of all I tried to "import" using

```
const net = require('react-native-tcp-socket');
```

And that gave another error

```
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'Sockets.connect')
```

So after someone suggested to me on Reddit, I had to eject the code with "expo eject" then rebuild the app using "expo run:android" and that worked!

So if anyone's struggling with this might wanna try that.